# Precision 1nA - 10mA current source

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source

I need design a variable precision current source which able to produce 1nA to 10mA. The current output will be controlled through a Micro controller using a DAC. The purpose this circuit is to calibrate another device which need 1nA to 10mA.

I did some research and found below options:

1. Analog Devices: [Precision Nanoamp Bidirectional Current Source](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/reference-designs/circuit-collections/precision-nanoamp-bidirectional-current-source.html)
   Not enough information  to how can be modified for my application
2. simple [opamp and Mosfet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0151.pdf) which output current should be I = Vdac/(R4 or R3) Figure
3. Also I read about  [Multi-Range Current Pump](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa474a/snoa474a.pdf) too.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdltHi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(*forget about the part numbers on drawing, just for reference)

Please let me know if any of these option will work for me, or if there is better option out there.

How can I design a precision 1nA - 10mA current source circuit?

Comment: 1 nA to 10 mA is a range of 1:10\$^7\$. A 12-bit DAC has a resolution of 1:4096. How do you plan on doing this?

Comment: @Transistor - The schematic does have a range select where either 100Ohm or 1Megohm is used in the source of the FET, extending the range by 10^4.

Comment: You can apply different circuit topologies  to different current ranges and switch their outputs with reed-relays (low-leakage). At the nA scale you will want to go the op-amp route because of the plethora of opamps which have their input bias current tested/characterized/guaranteed in the pA and fA ranges (finding equivalent discrete FETs not as easy).

Comment: Adaptation of https://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These circuits work well, I've built several variations of them to deliver accurate amounts of current, but mostly on the load side. I have a few suggestions:

- Use a low noise amplifier
- Use a low leakage mosfet
- Make sure the feedback loop is compensated properly, the mosfet has small amounts of capacitance and can create poles in the kHz to MHz range. If the poles are higher than the DC gain, then this can create a resonance point and causes oscillations. The best way is to simulate in SPICE with different DC levels while running an AC analysis to ensure stability.
- Make sure you use a low noise DAC
- If you use a MUX put the feedback loop so it includes the mux (this is a big hint).
- Instead of a mux, if the leakage could be controlled, you might be able to use two circuits in parallel.

[image]

The circuit above simulates down to 1nA with a 1mV input.

If you need absolute calibration to a specific level of current, I'd buy a Keithly current source meter (like the 2400 Keithly SMU)

Comment: Thanks for the detail comment, what do you mean by keep the mux in feedback loop, since the mux is choosing the R6 resistor. I can not use two difference circuit because I need be able to  generate nano , micro, and mA which need more than two circuit.

Comment: So, if you roll the mux into the feedback loop the feedback will make it look like the mux isn't there, you might need two muxes to do this.

Comment: I am still confuse, I will be appreciated if you can draw me an schematic

Comment: I question the location of C3.

Comment: @EinarA And you have a better location?

Comment: No. But it is usually connected straight to the opamp output and I wondered if it was a mistake or if there is a better reason to connect it as shown.

Comment: The AC response works better with C3 at that location, you can also adjust R3 to give you more or less bandwidth (usually you want less)